# How to enable USB Debug on OPPO device without display warning message on notification panel

Tags: android, security, notifications, usb-debugging, oppo

I tried hard to stop this `warning message` but I still don't have solution for this.
If anyone know the best solution please share here.
These are reasons why:

1. It is `annoy` for my development
2. It can be disable when I touch on it by `mistake`. Actually I don't want to disable it. I just want to enable it for long time like other devices (Samsung,LG,...)

[image: screnn]

Comment: what's your purpose? are you a developer or user?

Comment: I am developer.

Comment: For my previous experience, I can enable developer option without showing up warning message like this. But after I disable and enable it again, it still keep the original configuration.

Comment: Since you are a developer, I just wondering why you care about the warning message? since you cannot change the behaviors of end user

Comment: You're right bro! but why I care about it? Because it only happened on OPPO devices. And it is annoy for my development. So it is better if we have solution for this.

Comment: Is this developer mode warning always visible or only on the launcher screen?

Comment: It always visible on every screens.

Answer (score 1):

I have solution by trying to use additional application like [Status](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.james.status) or 
[Material Status Bar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.treydev.msb). But it is not the best solution for you.